# How to use google map iframe embed code in react.js

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I am using react.js. I have to display the map on my contact us page so I added iframe embed code which I got from the google map. I am using the below code. I am not using any API.

```
import React from 'react';

const AddressMap=()=>{
  return(
    <div className="google-map-code">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d15282225.79979123!2d73.7250245393691!3d20.750301298393563!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x30635ff06b92b791%3A0xd78c4fa1854213a6!2sIndia!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1587818542745!5m2!1sen!2sin" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>

    </div>

  );
}
export{AddressMap}
```

I am getting the error on my page

> Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to
>   values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing +
>   'em'}} when using JSX.

Would you help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In react style expects an object. e.g: `style={{border:0}}`

```js
import React from 'react';
const AddressMap = () => {
    return (
        <div className="google-map-code">
            <iframe
                src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d15282225.79979123!2d73.7250245393691!3d20.750301298393563!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x30635ff06b92b791%3A0xd78c4fa1854213a6!2sIndia!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1587818542745!5m2!1sen!2sin"
                width="600"
                height="450"
                frameborder="0"
                style={{ border: 0 }}
                allowfullscreen=""
                aria-hidden="false"
                tabindex="0"
            />
        </div>
    );
};
export { AddressMap };
```

Comment: Yes, it's working. I want to you why you used style={{border:0}}?

Comment: In React, inline styles are not specified as a string. Instead, they are specified with an object whose key is the camelCased version of the style name, and whose value is the style's value, usually a string. please refer: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer please upvote and accept it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";

const GoogleMap = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <iframe
        title="google map"
        src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3473115.9060003995!2d-9.790797163012584!3d31.778265070846214!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0xd0b88619651c58d%3A0xd9d39381c42cffc3!2sMorocco!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sma!4v1709282907766!5m2!1sen!2sma"
        width="100%"
        height="500"
        style={{ border: 0 }}
        allowfullscreen=""
        loading="lazy"
        referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GoogleMap;
```

you should to add title because in React for each  elements must have a unique title property